# decodeStream: Is an image first downloaded and then downsized?

Tags: android, performance, bitmap

I am downloading some images from urls in my app, and when I get to decoding a URL into a bitmap WITH BitmapFactoryOptions inSampleSize size set to > 0, I just think it takes too much time.

The problem is that it takes too much time decoding.. on a local network with the server I spend around 1.2 seconds decoding with inSampleSize set to 8.

For comparison I then did timing of just using decodeStream(inputStream) without options: the time of execution was roughly the same (1.1-1.2 seconds)

The particular image is around 2.5 MB ( I know its a bit bulky to begin with, but its good to use large ones now to test performance)

My Question is, does decodeStream downloads the whole image and then uses the opts inSampleSize param to downsize my Bitmap or should it downsize "on the fly"? (i.e. instead of just downloading 2.5 MB straight it just downloads 1/8 of it, due to my inSampleSize param?)

Comment: It downloads the whole image and then downsizes it. If you want to avoid 2.5 MB being downloaded over a mobile internet connection you have to use a backend server to which you pass the url (you could do this in PHP). It then downloads the image and sends a smaller version of the image to your app.

Comment: `It downloads the whole image and then downsizes it`. Are you sure? I think it will download and resize while downloading. It will not first resize after complete download. Anyhow. All has to be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for quick replies. I seen people use FilterInputStream to wrap the inputStream, which implements the skip() method.. Not sure how that works, but maybe that can use skip to skip every nth byte? Reducing the download size?

Comment: @greenapps I'm pretty sure! But if you don't find this detail in the documentation you will have to use a network sniffer to be sure.

Comment: @vankiz In how far would it make sense to skip a byte? Think about my backend idea. Would be quite simple too!

Comment: Could you please provide a short step by step for server side to do this? In my app I do not directly communicate with my PHP, I just give a direct URL to the image hosted on my server.

Comment: @haywire a network snifler will tell nothing about what is done with the passing bytes.

Comment: @greenapps it will tell you if the image was downloaded in "one piece" or chunk by chunk and processed. if the latter is the case the download would've taken slightly more time.

Comment: @haywire No wireshark will never be able to tell what the receiver did with the chunks. And indeed they come chunk by chunk as that is how tcp/ip works. Wireshark sees the bytes passing by but will never know what the rerceiver did with them.